# How to speed up plotly boxplots with many points and boxpoints = all

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, boxplot, r-plotly

I'm trying to write a `shiny` app where a dataset with about 30k rows is filtered by 3 user inputs. The outputs are:

1. a `leaflet` map showing some spatial information for aggregated data values;
2. a `plotly` boxplot showing the temporal trend of raw data values.

Clicking on each marker on the `leaflet` map highlights the corresponding values in the `plotly` boxplot, and selecting points on the latter plot, highlights the matching marker on the map. These two functionalities require showing all the raw data values in the boxplot.

The app I've written runs relatively smooth, so far. Unfortunately, the dataset is going to double its size in about 6 months and the project is (hopefully) going to last for 10 years, leading to a total of more than 600k estimated rows. Also, the app is going to be run by about 50 users simultaneously, so it needs to be fast and efficient.

At the moment, the slowest part seems to be printing all the data points with `plotly`.
This is also showed by the following example with the `diamonds` dataset.

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

my_data <- data.table(diamonds) %>% 
            setkey

min_carat <- min(my_data$carat)
max_carat <- max(my_data$carat)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 3,
      sliderInput("carat",
                  label = "diamond carat",
                  min = min_carat,
                  max = max_carat,
                  value = max_carat)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("boxplot")
    )
  )
)

# Plotly Boxplot
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
filtered_data <- reactive(my_data[carat <= input$carat,])
  
  output$boxplot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(source = "boxplot") %>%
      add_trace(
        data = filtered_data(),
        x = ~cut,
        y = ~price,
        color = ~I("gray"),
        marker = list(
          color = "black"
        ),
        line = list(color = "black"),
        type = "box",
        boxpoints = "all",
        pointpos = 0,
        jitter = 0.5
      ) %>%
      layout(
        xaxis = list(
          fixedrange = TRUE
        ),
        yaxis = list(
          fixedrange = TRUE
        )
      )
  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Unfortunately, for the `box` traces, `scattergl` seems to be not available ([Issue #2534](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2534)) and `scatter` traces don't have a `jitter` option ([Issue #299](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/299)).

Any ideas or workarounds to improve the performances of the app?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Here](https://plotly.com/python/v3/compare-webgl-svg/#svg) you can find a UserWarning summarizing the issue: `Due to browser limitations, the Plotly SVG drawing functions have a hard time graphing more than 500k data points for line charts, or 40k points for other types of charts.` (from plotly.py which under the hood - just as the R API - uses plotly.js)